# What's the differences between sys.dm_exec_query_stats and sys.dm_exec_cached_plans?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, dmv, metadata

As per my understandings, from `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`, we can cross apply other DMFs to get the statement level cached plans and the query text. From `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`, we can get the cached plans and the query text (by cross apply other DMFs). So what's the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of getting the plan, using sys.dm_exec_query_stats you can use statement_start_offset and End offset to get the plan for individual statement in a stored procedure.

Eg

```
select top 100 object_name(object_id),ps.execution_count as proc_exec_count, qs.plan_generation_num, qs.execution_count as Stmt_exec_count,qs.total_elapsed_time/qs.execution_count as AVG_Run_Time,   qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time,
qs.last_elapsed_time, qs.min_elapsed_time, qs.max_elapsed_time,qs.min_rows,qs.max_rows,
SUBSTRING ([st].[text], 
        ([qs].[statement_start_offset] / 2) + 1, 
        ((CASE [statement_end_offset] 
            WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH ([st].[text]) 
            ELSE [qs].[statement_end_offset] END 
            - [qs].[statement_start_offset]) / 2) + 1) 
            AS [StatementText],cast(s3.query_plan as xml) query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats ps  
JOIN [sys].[dm_exec_query_stats] AS [qs]
        ON [ps].[plan_handle] = [qs].[plan_handle]
cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan ([qs].[plan_handle], statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) s3
CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text]    ([qs].[sql_handle]) AS [st]
where database_id=db_id('DB') --and qs.execution_count >100 
and object_id in (object_id('SP Name')) 
ORDER BY avg_run_time DESC
```

And obviously it has different information regarding query execution stats and plans.